# Image resize to browser without cropping or loosing aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-resizing

I am working on a responsive template.
I have pages with images and I want them to look like this : http://www.chanel.com/fr_FR/

I can't figure out a css way to achieve it so I am trying jquery although I ain't the best jquery coder...

This is what I end up with : 
html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="text" >
            <p>some text</p>
        <div>
        <div class="image" >
            <img class="adapt" src="my-image.jpeg" alt="my image">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {          
            function imageResize() { 
            var wrapH = $('div.image').height();
            var imgH = $('img.adapt').height();
            var wrapW = $('div.image').width();
            var imgW = $('img.adapt').width();
                $("img.adapt").css("height", (wrapH < imgH) ? wrapH : "auto");
                $("img.adapt").css("width", (wrapW < imgW) ? wrapW : "auto");
            }
            imageResize();
            $(window).bind("resize", function(){
                imageResize();  
            });  
        }); 

  </script>
```

css

```
div.text {
position : absolute;
width : 40%
left : 0;
top : 0;
}

div.image{
    position: absolute;
    top : 0;
    right : 0;
    left : 40%;
    width : 60%;
    bottom : 150px;
}
```

This seems to work when I enlarge the browser but when I make it smaler, the image flickers and its ugly...

If some pro jquery coder can explain this problem to me, I would be very graitfull.

Answer (score 1):

If you download Google Chrome, browser to that page again, and look under the resources tab in developer tools, view the author's styles.css file.  Around line 800 and lower, you will see that the author is using media queries to get that responsive feel that you are looking for.  The author is also taking advantage of percentages to design width, height, margin and padding of elements and various items.  No need for jQuery just yet.  Simply dive into the world of media queries first to get a feel for true responsive design.  Then when you become comfortable, go ahead and apply some creative animations via jQuery to spice things up.

Comment: If you see more deeply in source, you will see that author (Clement Caillard) is using some nice javascript/jquery functions to keep it fully functional, just like you said.

Comment: ok I'll have a closer look at it but can the flickering effect be solved by modifuing my code?

Comment: Flickering tends to be a common issue on various jQuery frameworks.  I honestly do not know the answer to fixing that.